# Energy transmission from opposite magnetic field vectors. A wire with a current in a homogenous magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, electromagnetic-induction

This is my first post and also the first time I've ever tried understanding a physics concept by approaching it with my own math logic so tips on trying to do this more effectively are also welcome

I’m trying to understand the link between a force experienced by a wire in a homogenous magnetic field and the magnetic field created by the current in the wire.

I noticed that the force vector is always directly towards the spot on the circle where the homogenous magnetic field and the magnetic field created by the current "cancel each other out" and I’m trying to figure out how they relate to each other.

I added together the vectors of the homogenous magnetic field and the wire’s magnetic field (the wire’s magnetic field vector is the tangent of the circular magnetic field around the wire) and drew the resulting vector lines when the homogenous magnetic field and the wire’s magnetic fields are equal. Just to visualize the interactions between the magnetic fields somehow.

I noticed that they only cancel each other out in 1 specific spot but I don’t quite understand the link between the force, the direction of the force vector and the magnetic fields "cancelling each other out" (or the vectors just pointing in opposite directions). you can strengthen the homogenous magnetic field which results in a stronger current and therefore force or you can increase the current which results in a stronger magnetic field of the wire and thereby also force.

So how is the energy converted from magnetic fields "cancelling each other out" in a specific point to a force and why is the force vector always pointing to this point?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The combination of magnetic fields is sometimes called the *catapult field* as illustrated below.

[image]

The name catapult field comes from the idea that magnetic field lines are always in a state of tension and are trying to straighten out just like the rubber band in a catapult.

Where the magnetic fields cancel out is called a *neutral point* and is beneath the wire in the diagram above.

Comment: Thanks! This makes intuitive sense.